# Breaker for subpanel keeps tripping after rainstorm

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, subpanel, outdoor

My neighbor has a large main panel where pg and e comes in, and his panel has a breaker that feeds a subpanel which sends power to a cabin(mine) my landlords shop, her house and some outdoor gfi outlets, 4 breakers total in this sub panel. Ever since a large rainstorm the breaker for our subpanel keeps tripping its corresponding breaker on the
Neighbors main panel. The feeder wire for our subpanel is out door rated but got cut cut by a fallen tree branch long ago and was fixed with an open splice. I made absolutely sure to re-tape the cut red wire, and individually tape, each of the four wires inside the sheathing and then at the end, I taped the whole cluster together, even after all that the breaker for the sub panel at the neighbors. Main panel was still tripping. I’m at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure the taping job you did is fully weather proof? It sounds to me that water/moisture is creating a short or a ground fault there.

Comment: The breaker that is tripping: does it have a TEST button? *The feeder wire for our subpanel is out door rated but got cut cut by a fallen tree branch long ago and was fixed with an open splice.* Fix that crud.  Harper's Rule: when you're having a problem you can't identify, but you have a *known problem* you're refusing to fix, fixing the known problem often fixes the other problem.  Overhead lines should be unreachable and underground lines need to be at 6-24" burial depending on conduit type. If you just laid it across the ground, then your bad practices are at the heart of your problem.

Comment: The word landlord means a rental.  Rentals and electricity means only license electricians can do the work, to be legal in most places.  Tape on the ground is not good enough, you need water proof splices.

Comment: Good thing nobody's been electrocuted by all that rain when you've got an uninsulated feeder wire laying on the ground in the puddles.

Comment: Is it even legal to be piggy-backing onto your neighbor's electricity hookup like that? I suspect that doing so at least violates PG&E's supply agreement with the neighbor ...

Comment: @brhans it does sound like there's something unconventional here. Maybe it's a single parcel of land for tax and utility connection purposes, with a "home" and multiple "accessory dwelling unit" or "outbuilding" structures providing the housing.

Comment: *Note that this is happening right after California is having infamously massive rains*. Methinks the splice was done entirely sub-par. Also it lacks the mandatory 24" of cover on an unprotected cable.  Also it may be NM-B cable which has been wrecked by the rain now.